# Calculate average RGB value of a PPM file

Tags: c, average, rgb

I am attempting to calculate the average RGB value of a PPM image. My attempt can be seen in the code below, but when I run the solution the output in cmd is: 0 0 0

I feel that the line of code in my attempt `int clr = fscanf(f, "%i %i %i", &x, &y, &z);` is also incorrect- I attempted to use fscanf as a substitute for the getPixel() which makes use of the (apparently) dated "graphics.h" header.

To summarise:

**1. How can I calculate and print the average RGB values of a PPM file?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Image size 
#define WIDTH 2048 
#define HEIGHT 2048

int main()
{
int x, y, z;

//Used for tally
int R = 0;
int G = 0;
int B = 0;

//Loop count value
int total = 0;

//File handle 
FILE *f; 

//File open 
f = fopen("Dog2048x2048.ppm", "r"); 

if (f == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: file could not be opened");
    exit(1);
}

//Iterate through the image width and height 
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
    {
        //Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
        int clr = fscanf(f, "%i %i %i", &x, &y, &z);

        R += clr;
        G += clr;
        B += clr;

        total++;
    }
}

//Calculate average
R /= total;
G /= total;
B /= total;

//Print RGB 
printf("%i %i %i", R, G, B);

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You're not accounting for the header part of the file (Which includes things like the width and height of the image... You shouldn't be hardcoding those values.)

Comment: And look up the documentation for `fscanf()` to see what it returns. Then think about how you're using that value...

Comment: I assume it's an ascii P3 format PPM since you're using `fscanf()`, but you might want to check to confirm that when reading the header and error on a P6 one (Or also read that format). If it is P3, and the image has comments in it, you have to factor those in too when reading the file.

Comment: `R += x; G += y, etc.`  You're at best adding 3 to R,G,and B each time, and worst adding 0 if scanf is failing. You're also not accounting for the header and such assuming you have a complete P3 text PPM file.

Comment: Note: With `2048x2048`, `R` can be as much as 50% `INT_MAX`.  Consider  `long long R = 0;` if files could get much larger.

Comment: read these values: `#define WIDTH 2048 
#define HEIGHT 2048` from the header of the file.  Also read the number of bytes of each pixel from the header of the file (don't assume 3 bytes)  And the `width` needs to be rounded up to a multiple of 2

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: [PPM format](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=format+of+a+PPM+file&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)  and [PPM format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Comment: this also may be very helpful: [PPM format](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/ppm-files.pdf)

Comment: @chux It can actually get bigger than `INT_MAX` with a 2048x2048 image, since the maximum color value is 65535.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help of each user who commented/shared their solution on this question, I think I now have a solution which is functioning the way I want it to as seen below.

The code prints out the ppm file in format below, and then goes on to find the average RGB value of the file which is printed to cmd.

```
P6 
# ignores comments in header 
width 
height 
max colour value
```

My working solution attempt as seen below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
} pixel;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

char magic_number[1];
int w, h, m;
int red = 0; 
int green = 0; 
int blue = 0;
int total = 0;      //Loop count initialised at 0 
FILE* f;            //File handle
pixel currentPix;   //Variable declaration for the current pixel 

//Open and read the PPM file 
f = fopen("Dog2048x2048.ppm", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: file cannot be opened");
    exit(1);
}

//Get P6, width, height, maxcolour value 
fscanf(f, "%s %d %d %d", &magic_number, &w, &h, &m);
printf("magic_n = %s, width = %d, height = %d, max_colour = %d\n", magic_number, w, h, m);

//iterate through the height and width of the ppm file 
for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {

        //Read data from the given stream 
        fread(&currentPix, 3, 1, f);

        //Stores current pixel RGB values in red, green, blue variables
        red += currentPix.r;
        green += currentPix.g;
        blue += currentPix.b;

        //Counts the iterations 
        total++; 
    }
}

//calculate averages for red, green, blue
red /= total;
green /= total;
blue /= total;

//print output of average rgb 
printf("%d, %d, %d", red, green, blue);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The file [`Dog2048x2048.ppm`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mondus/COM4521_mosaic/master/Dog2048x2048.ppm) is indeed a P6 format PPM as defined is this [PPM Format Specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html). As such, it has its samples represented not as text, but *in pure binary*, thus not `fscanf(…%i…)`, but rather `fread()` is appropriate for reading them, e. g. for the file at hand with *Maxval* 255:

```
    // skip over P6\n2048\n2048\n255\n
    if (fscanf(f, "P6 2048 2048%d%*c", &z) < 1)
        puts("unexpected format of file"), exit(1);

    // Iterate through the image width and height 
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
    {   // Note that you mixed up WIDTH and HEIGHT - just doesn't matter here
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++)
        {
            //Color clr = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
            unsigned char clr[3];
            if (fread(clr, 3, 1, f) < 1)
                printf("read error at %d,%d\n", i, j), exit(1);

            R += clr[0];
            G += clr[1];
            B += clr[2];
            total++;
        }
    }
```